# Não consigo redirecionar com PHP usando o header()

Tags: php

Galera preciso de ajuda, sou iniciante e fiz o script abaixo onde recebo dados de um formulário, salvo em um arquivo csv, e depois libero o download de um pdf, no entanto, no final do script, eu queria dar um `header()` para a index para apagar os dados do formulário, porém não estou conseguindo de forma alguma redirecionar, o pdf já baixa automaticamente, mas não redireciona. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao SOpt, Jande. O que aparece na tela? Há alguma mensagem? É sempre ideal usar somente texto ao mandar algum código ao invés de imagem com código, pois, ao mandar imagem, dificulta nos testes aqui.

Comment: Olá jande, poderia postar seu código invés da imagem?

Comment: Não relacionado à pergunta, mas se vc tem `if(...) { faz_coisas; faz_A; } else { faz_A; }`, vc só precisa de `if(...) { faz_coisas; } faz_A;`

Comment: @tvdias ajustei a resposta, acho que esta boa agora, aonde você acha que ela esta ruim exatamente para justificar o seu downvote

Answer (score 9):

O problema todo é que você não entende HTTP ainda, eu vou falar algo, a maioria diz entender HTTP, acha que estudando um dia ou dois domina isso, mas é pura ilusão, é necessário entender o que é TCP e, depois, entender o que é HTTP.

Você está esperando um comportamento do servidor como se estivesse correndo no computador do usuário, mas não está, porque o script está no servidor, **isso não é um comando:**

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

E nem nenhum outro `header` é um comando no PHP, são todos instruções, que serão baixadas e processadas pelo programa do lado cliente ou pelo **SAPI** (**S**erver **A**pplication **P**rogramming **I**nterface, neste caso são algumas instruções especiais como o `X-Send` citado pelo colega [@Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/70/bacco) que só correm do lado servidor comunicando um script com um módulo do servidor, mas isto é outra história), sejam eles:

- navegadores
- programas como curl, de comando de linha
- Web Crawlers (Spider ou Bot)

### Entendendo um pouco do HTTP

Eu já vou adiantar, não adianta sair daqui achando que aprendeu, ou que vai dominar isso de verdade, a maioria não domina, só se ilude e leva tempo para entender sim, ainda mais se não entende o básico e TCP, mas sim dá pra explicar o HTTP sem me aprofundar muito no TCP, a explicação mais simples, mas que não vai tornar ninguém em especialista é, quando você faz qualquer requisição HTTP o programa cliente, como navegadores irá enviar uma **instrução** para o servidor, algo como:

```
GET /pasta/arquivo.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.site.com
Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg, */*
Accept-Language: en-us
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0
(linha em branco)
```

O `(linha em branco)` é uma linha vazia, deve ir depois dos headers, em GET é "indiferente", geralmente os servidores tratam isso, mas em POST, PUT e PATCH quando contêm payload (informação de um formulário por exmeplo).

Então o navegador envia isto tudo puramente **COMO TEXTO**, subindo completamente o **SERVIDOR** vai processar e entender a instrução e irá agora enviar um download, sim um download, tudo em HTTP é download, então isto vai sendo baixado e só é processado pelo front-end quando algumas partes vão estar sendo reajustados, exemplo (só coloquei um pedaço, porque um PDF seria grande)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 06 Feb 2020 23:15:53 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 06 Feb 2020 15:24:18 GMT
Content-Length: ‭1048576‬
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='arquivo.pdf'
Location: index.php

%PDF-1.7

4 0 obj
...
```

Então o navegador irá interpretar os headers, como existe o header:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

ou o:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment
```

Faz com que o navegador *CANCELE* a requisição (em navegadores), sim ele cancela e direciona para o gerenciador de downloads, claro que isso depende do motor e de como ele funciona gerencia o download, então a resposta HTTP deixa de ser controlada pela aba/janela que solicitou e passa a ser controlado pelo **gerenciador de downloads**, o gerenciador não faz parte do **motor de renderização**

O gerenciador de download pode vir embutido no navegador e não quer dizer que faça parte dele "completamente", mas claro que ele processa a mesma sessão que estava na aba/janela e você pode observar que no momento que o download inicia o "gerenciador" a requisição HTTP está marcada como cancelada no "navegador", você pode observar isto no console (DevTools por exemplo) na aba rede.

Para resumir como as headers são tratadas depende de onde é executado, em `XmlHttpRequest` o comportamento/tratamento dos headers recebidos é outro e dependendo do cliente como `curl` (comando de linha) isto também pode variar, ou seja cada tipo de local pode tratar os headers de forma diferente, podendo ser por ordem ou até por prioridade definida pelo programa cliente.

### Não é possível redirecionar após um download

Resumindo, **não é o PHP** que faz o redirecionamento, quem faz é quem vai interpretar os headers e também não é possível direcionar após um download começar porque geralmente gerenciadores de download necessitam cancelar em uma instância (navegador) para que eles possam controlar a requisição

O unico meio de contornar isto seria fazendo talvez via JavaScript e no front-end, fazendo o download e o redirecionamento serem janelas diferentes, um exemplo superficial (afinal não tenho como saber exatamente como esta o seu sistema, basta ajustar a sua necessidade):

```
//Arquivo hipotético
$arquivo = '../foo/bar.csv';
?>
<script>
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.style.display = "none";
  a.href = "<?php echo $arquivo ?>";
  a.setAttribute("download", fileName);

  document.body.appendChild(a);

  a.click();

  //Redireciona via JavaScript
  setTimeout(function () {
      window.location = "index.php";
  }, 10);
</script>
<?php
} else {
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Comment: Porque o negativo? Quem negativou discorda que HTTP funcione assim? Ou acredita que HTTP e TCP é fácil de entender?

Comment: @tvdias tem muitas formas de resolver no front-end, mas depende do conhecimento do usuário que pergunta, no geral eu nem devia ter dado sugestão, porque isso é especifico pode ser que em um ambiente especifico não dê para implementar assim, se as pessoas se preocupassem em aprender o minimo do que é web, e web é HTTP, então saberiam como contornar para cada situação problemas assim, mas como as pessoas aprendem errado é necessário explicar o que é HTTP e esperar que a pessoa modifique/adapte o que fez a sua própria necessidade, o que foi q tentei ensinar.

Comment: Só adicionei o exemplo pra tentar ajudar, mas é como disse não servirá para todos casos, a parte importante é entender como HTTP funciona e então ajustar e até ver uma estratégia melhor, que pode ser a que apresentei ou a que você apresentou, ou até uma série de outras que só vendo o sistema completo dele poderiamos saber.

Comment: @tvdias sim, mas ai esta o problema, o download é forçado via PHP, ele poderia forçar com .htaccess+mod_headers (recursos do Apache) e resolver o resto todo no front-end de forma simples, ele pode ter escolhido o FORM, mas foi decisão dele, nem significa que é a melhor estratégia, é mais provável q ele escolheu pq não sabe bem os princípios básicos, esse é o tipo de pergunta problematica que se enquadra em um dos fechamento off-topic, mas respondi pq fiquei com dó dele não entender HTTP... PS: Que outra pergunta (isto: apesar de ter sido questionado em outra pergunta por fazer isso)?

Comment: Parabéns pela resposta @GuilhermeNascimento bem elaborada e esclarecedora!

Comment: @tvdias acho que depende, tem que analisar caso a caso, aqui o problema justamente era o entendimento falho do autor que precisava ser orientado e talvez no que você respondeu pode ser outra coisa totalmente diferente, mas só eu vendo o link pra ter certeza.

Comment: Sim, sempre depende. TB sou recente no SOpt e "aprendendo" como ele funciona. Por sinal, já cometi inúmeras gafes... rs Estou tentando participar bastante, trocar idéias, etc. Quero ver até quando vou conseguir manter o ritmo!

Comment: @tvdias Excelente! Isso mesmo, sempre procure a pró-atividade e sempre buscar dicas. Boa sorte e se quiser trocar alguma ideia é bem vindo no chat do site https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha

Answer (score 1):

Pela imagem, notei que você faz o uso do [readfile](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.readfile.php), esse método lê um arquivo e escreve o seu conteúdo para o buffer de saída (output buffer).

Via regra, você não pode enviar um cabeçalho depois que iniciou a transmissão do conteúdo (que é o que o readfile está fazendo).

Imagino que você esteja tentando fazer o download de um arquivo, provavelmente com um `target='_blank'` no seu php, e por isso está tentando fazer o redirect com o `header`.

Quando você retornar um header `application/octet-stream` o próprio browser irá iniciar o download, então acredito que você pode chamar o seu download diretamente da página `home`, remover esse `header("Location: home.php");` e o comportamento será o esperado.

Caso não seja esse seu cenário, atualize sua pergunta com mais detalhes, que complemento a resposta.

Comment: Faltou responder como limpar o formulário ao fazer o download...